# React-native-safe-area-context not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-safe-area-view

When building with android studio, I get the following error:

```
error: package com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext does not exist
```

I'm using

```
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.6",
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work? It seems that the package is offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Yarn, try to:

1. Remove the package with yarn remove
2. Reset the cache with yarn cache clean
3. Reinstall the package with yarn add

Do the same with other package managers